# Is there a way to create a bode plot using hertz instead of rad/s?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to create a bode plot using hertz instaead of rads/s, but I don't know how to do that.

My code right now is:

```
R1 = 200
R2 = 1000
C1 = 2.5*10^-5
C2 = 1*10^-6
G = ((1/(s*C1))*R2)/((1/(s^2*C1*C2))+(R2/(s*C1))+(R1/(s*C1))+R1*R2+(1/(s*C2)))
bode(G)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the doc for [bodeplot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bodeplot.html), and/or [setoptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/setoptions.html).  The example from the doc is:

```
>> sys = tf(1,[1 1]);
>> h = bodeplot(sys);
>> p = getoptions(h);
>> p.FreqUnits = 'Hz';
>> setoptions(h,p);
```